# How can I put this equation in terms of x?

Tags: calculus

The equation is this:

$ y = x^2+x-1 $

I tried:

$ x = \sqrt{y+1-x} $

But it left one $x$ in the other side of the $=$

I searched a little in the Internet and also tried to "complete the square", but I think this is obviusly incorrect:

$$ y = (x^2+x+1/4)-1-1/4 \\
y+5/4=(x+1/2)^2 \\
\sqrt{y+5/4}=\sqrt{(x+1/2)^2}\\
\sqrt{y+5/4}-1/2=x$$

Comment: Have you ever heard about the quadratic formula?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second attempt is correct. You have only to take into account the fact that $a^2 = b^2 \implies a = \pm b$ and so the result is:
$$ x = -1/2 \pm \sqrt{y + 5/4} $$